# Rails 5 capistrano assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm using rails 5 **api only** application. And when I'm trying to deploy this application getting error

```
Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@xxx.xxx.xxx: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'assets:precompile' (see --tasks)
/home/deploy/applications/myrento/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How do I turn off deploy:assets:precompile task?

This is my Capfile

```
require "capistrano/setup" 
require "capistrano/deploy" 
require "capistrano/rbenv" 
require "capistrano" 
require "capistrano/rails" 
require "capistrano/bundler" 
require "capistrano/postgresql" 
require "capistrano/puma" 
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

Comment: can you post your `Capfile` ?

Comment: `require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"
require "capistrano/rbenv"
require "capistrano"
require "capistrano/rails"
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/postgresql"
require "capistrano/puma"
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }`

Answer (score 4):

To remove asset compilation, you can remove this:

```
require "capistrano/rails"
```

And add,

```
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
```